# Applying VBA Code on all sheets

Tags: vba, excel

My VBA code sorts a sheet by a certain column, i.e. "AT". What I like to have is for this VBA to apply on all the sheets of the workbook at the same time. My original working code looks like this:

```
Dim sort As String
Dim area As String
area = "A4:FJ4100"
sort = "AT"
ActiveSheet.Range(area).Sort _
Key1:=Range(sort & "1"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
Header:=xlGuess, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

I tried adding

```
dim sh as Worksheet 
For each sh in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 
sh.activate 
"my code"
Next
```

but this does not work. Happy for any help!

Comment: This is strange, your code should be actually working. Can you go step-by-step with `F8` and confirm what is not working? Actually, the only chance not to work is to have your code in a Worksheet, and not in a Module. If you put it to a Module, it should work.

Comment: elaborate on 'this does not work' please. how does this not work? what happens instead?

Comment: no error is shown. but it doesn't apply on the 2nd sheet.

Comment: that would be because you are turning screen updating off with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` after the first run, so you dont see the changes your code makes on the rest of the sheets.

Comment: Doubt that would be the case Banana, it should refresh after the last line of code (e.g. finished macro)....shouldn't it?

Comment: @JvdV is right...I changed it and this was not the case

Comment: @os23 please post your whole complete code that handles the sorting. i still believe that the culprit is ScreenUpdating, but maybe you have something else in addition to ScreenUpdating that also affect the sorting. for example, you have 2 issues that i can see, one is the screen updating and the other one is using `ActiveSheet` instead of `sh`. the `sh` issue was corrected in @Vityata 's answer however he/she didnt correct the screen updating issue. are you sure that you fixed both points from above or only one each time?

Comment: @Banana here is the modified code which does not work. maybe you can see the error very quick. thanks  

`Sub test()

Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
sh.Activate

Dim sort As String
Dim area As String
area = "A4:FJ4100"
sort = "AT"
sh.Range(area).sort _
Key1:=Range(sort & "1"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
Header:=xlGuess, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Next

End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to make your code working, if you put it in a module. It avoids `Select` and `Active`, thus it makes it a bit more robust:

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        SortSomething sh
    Next sh

End Sub

Sub SortSomething(sh As Worksheet)

    Dim sort As String
    Dim area As String
    area = "A4:FJ4100"
    sort = "AT"
    sh.Range(area).sort _
    Key1:=sh.Range(sort & "1"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
        Header:=xlGuess, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Vityata. But here I get a runtime error '1004' - all connected cells should have the same size. The tagged part is this one: "sh.Range(area).sort _
    Key1:=sh.Range(sort & "1"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
        Header:=xlGuess, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom"

Comment: @os23 - are you having merged cells somewhere there?

Comment: no but a previous VBA hides some rows in all the sheets of the workbook. and on these lists with the hidden rows I want to apply the mentioned code above. I don't know if this would cause a problem

Comment: @os23 - The best way is to try to unhide the rows and see.

Comment: unfortunately the list comes with this 1st VBA already applied on and there is no chance to reverse it.

Comment: This code to sort the cells in column AT is actually a part of the total VBA. The other parts are codes to hide some columns and also rows. My added code lines work perfectly on these parts so that every sheet of the workbook is changed. Only this part with sorting a column is causing problems.

Comment: Put: 'Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False',  and 'Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False' in your code to unhide all rows and columns like Vityata explains. Your code doesn't seem to be wrong. Must be something to do with the layout. Examine it closely

Comment: @JvdV - ok thanks, I will try my best and play with the given lines and hope to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

In your "For Each" loop, after the sheet activate, you need to apply the range on loop 'ws' var.
Try this, it's work fine for me :

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets

    Dim sort As String
    Dim area As String

    area = "A4:FJ4100"
    sort = "AT"
    ws.Activate 'First activate the sheet
    ws.Range(area).sort _
    Key1:=Range(sort & "1"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
    Header:=xlGuess, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but again I get a runtime error '1004' for the lines `ws.Range(area).sort _
    Key1:=Range(sort & "1"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
    Header:=xlGuess, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom`

Comment: Ok. If your sub is in Thisworkbook, try to move this sub in a new module ?

Comment: could you please explain me a little bit more what you mean? I'm more like a beginner here. Should I open a new Module2 and then copy the code into that?

Comment: I saw on the web that some users have corrected this kind of error by placing the code in a new module.
So yes, create a Module2 and try.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately not for me :( Still just works on only one worksheet.

Comment: Can we have screen shot of your first 10 rows? The area start Row 4 but sort is defined at AT1 (Row 1).

Comment: Actually the first row is completely empty. The 2nd and 3rd row are just topics (words). From the 4th row on there are only numbers which I'd like to sort on my two open worksheets in the workbook which represent the stats in two different years.

Comment: I created this short code and tried it on another very simple example workbook with multiple worksheets...and it works perfectly! 

`For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Activate
ws.Range("A:E", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address).Sort Key1:=[e3],n Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
Next ws`

But when I try a modified version on my original file I get a runtime error '1004' that all the connected cells have to be of the same size. So I now really believe the problem is totally the pre-macro that refuses my VBA to work like I wish.